Logarithmic Projection of World Map (tikz)
I'm trying to make what is called a "log-azimuthal" projection of a world map in Tikz. Below is me doing it manually by entering some cities and their ranges & bearings from an arbitrary location to sort of feel out the idea.
Any thoughts on how to import a set of data, each of which looks like, eg, "New York, 40.7128N, 70.0060W" and convert and project each in this way, using an arbitrary location as the centre?
It's not the maths I'm asking about so much as the looping & data handling in Tikz. But if you're feeling haversiny, any thoughts on the maths would be cool!

    \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (a) at (90:1cm);
    \coordinate (b) at (90:2cm);
    \coordinate (c) at (90:3cm);
    \coordinate (d) at (90:4cm);
    \coordinate (Exeter) at (306:1.71cm);
    \coordinate (Guildford) at (363:2.37cm);
    \coordinate (Goudhurst) at (360:2.49cm);
    \coordinate (Naples) at (324:3.24cm);
    \coordinate (Washington) at (192:3.76cm);
    \coordinate (NY) at (186:3.73cm);
    \coordinate (SL) at (330:3.95cm);
    \path[draw=lightgray] (1, 0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=360, radius=1];
    \path[draw=lightgray] (2, 0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=360, radius=2];
    \path[draw=lightgray] (3, 0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=360, radius=3];
    \path[draw=lightgray] (4, 0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=360, radius=4];
    \fill[black] circle (2pt) node[anchor=north] {\tiny\sf Swimbridge};
    \fill[black] (Exeter) circle (2pt) node[anchor=north] {\tiny\sf Exeter};
    \fill[black] (Guildford) circle (2pt) node[anchor=south] {\tiny\sf Guildford};
    \fill[black] (Goudhurst) circle (2pt) node[anchor=north] {\tiny\sf Goudhurst};
    \fill[black] (Naples) circle (2pt) node[anchor=north] {\tiny\sf Naples};
    \fill[black] (Washington) circle (2pt) node[anchor=north] {\tiny\sf Washington};
    \fill[black] (NY) circle (2pt) node[anchor=north] {\tiny\sf New York};
    \fill[black] (SL) circle (2pt) node[anchor=north] {\tiny\sf Sri Lanka};
    \fill[lightgray] (a) circle (0pt) node[anchor=south] {\tiny $10^1$ km};
    \fill[lightgray] (b) circle (0pt) node[anchor=south] {\tiny $10^2$ km};
    \fill[lightgray] (c) circle (0pt) node[anchor=south] {\tiny $10^3$ km};
    \fill[lightgray] (d) circle (0pt) node[anchor=south] {\tiny $10^4$ km};
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \end{document}


Can you show graphically how it should look like at the end?

The reason you're not getting any answers is probably because it's unclear what you're trying to do.
Your code is strange: you draw arcs from 0° to 360°, which is usually done with circles. Then you draw circles with a radius of  0pt in order to place node texts with them; although you know the polar coordinate syntax (in your coordinate definitions).
In short: your code could be improved and put together with 3 foreachloops. But, as I said, no one knows what you actually want to do...

For maps have a look here: https://ctan.org/topic/cartography

Thanks @cis, it's called a "log-azimuthal projection". Found some info (but not code) here: https://roughan.info/math/log-az/. Will edit question.

It may be a good idea to add a screenshot of your current result.

Hi! Can you share the data file? :) Can the answer be written to compile with LuaLaTeX?

Hello! I like making map projections in TikZ, and was wondering if this is what you meant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_azimuthal_equal-area_projection?

Here is a result of a first refactoring cycle. I focused on making the cities more accessible to algorithms. So I left the range things as is, more or less.

For systematics it's good to include the center, Swimbridge in this case.

Plotting cities relies on coordinate and name being the same. The nodes format is abstracted into cityN and cityS; there's only one anomaly in this example, while in general there can be more, making some default handling interesting.

For automation I see at least 2 routes: A) external creation of code fragments, B) delegating to expl3.


For route A you'd create this code by some other program, AND use \input{snippet.tex} instead.
    % ~~~ cities of interest ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  \input{snippet.tex}

%   \coordinate (Swimbridge)at (  0:0cm);   % for a more systematic approach
%   \coordinate (Exeter)    at (306:1.71cm);
%   \coordinate (Guildford) at (363:2.37cm);
%   \coordinate (Goudhurst) at (360:2.49cm);
%   \coordinate (Naples)    at (324:3.24cm);
%   \coordinate (Washington)at (192:3.76cm);
%   \coordinate (New York)  at (186:3.73cm);
%   \coordinate (Sri Lanka) at (330:3.95cm);
%
%   
%   % ~~~ cities plotted ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%   \foreach \c/\f in { Swimbridge/cityS, Exeter/cityS,    Guildford/cityN,
%                       Goudhurst/cityS,  Naples/cityS,    Washington/cityS,
%                       New York/cityS,   Sri Lanka/cityS}
%       \fill[black] (\c) circle (2pt) node[\f] {\c};

Route B I'd like to delegate to a more experienced user at the moment. It's not difficult, but I'm not that fluent in expl3 at the moment.


% ~~~ refactored ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    cityS/.style={anchor=north, font={\tiny\sf}},
    cityN/.style={anchor=south, font={\tiny\sf}},
 ]
    % ~~~ intended locations for the range labels ~~~~~
    \coordinate (a) at (90:1cm);
    \coordinate (b) at (90:2cm);
    \coordinate (c) at (90:3cm);
    \coordinate (d) at (90:4cm);   
    
    % ~~~ range circles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \foreach \i in {1,2,3,4}
        \path[draw=lightgray] (\i, 0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=360, radius=\i];

    % ~~~ range marks ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \fill[lightgray] (a) circle (0pt) node[anchor=south] {\tiny $10^1$ km};
    \fill[lightgray] (b) circle (0pt) node[anchor=south] {\tiny $10^2$ km};
    \fill[lightgray] (c) circle (0pt) node[anchor=south] {\tiny $10^3$ km};
    \fill[lightgray] (d) circle (0pt) node[anchor=south] {\tiny $10^4$ km};


    % ~~~ cities of interest ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \coordinate (Swimbridge)at (  0:0cm);   % for a more systematic approach
    \coordinate (Exeter)    at (306:1.71cm);
    \coordinate (Guildford) at (363:2.37cm);
    \coordinate (Goudhurst) at (360:2.49cm);
    \coordinate (Naples)    at (324:3.24cm);
    \coordinate (Washington)at (192:3.76cm);
    \coordinate (New York)  at (186:3.73cm);
    \coordinate (Sri Lanka) at (330:3.95cm);

    
    % ~~~ cities plotted ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \foreach \c/\f in { Swimbridge/cityS, Exeter/cityS,    Guildford/cityN,
                        Goudhurst/cityS,  Naples/cityS,    Washington/cityS,
                        New York/cityS,   Sri Lanka/cityS}
        \fill[black] (\c) circle (2pt) node[\f] {\c};
    
 \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}

